apache asynchttpclient pool pending list full
Our system uses asynchronous httpclient to call the third-party interface. After running for a period of time, a circuit breaker occurs. After investigation, we found that the connection pool cannot obtain the connection. After restarting, it can run stably for a period of time. When the problem occurred, there were a large number of CLOSE WAIT state connections for the specified third-party interface. The maximum number of connections was set to 1200, and there were 1200 CLOSE WAIT connections. The PengDing queue of the connection pool had 1200, and then there were nearly 10,000 more. requests queued to obtain a connection
httpnio-core：4.4.6
httpasyncclient：4.1.3
JDK1.8
1：JDK1.8 97-> 1.8 333 not work
2：httpasyncclient 4.1.3 -> 4.1.5 not work
The link below has the same problem as mine
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HTTPASYNC/issues/HTTPASYNC-109?filter=recentlyviewed

What is your question? Did you already see [ask]?

i watn konw why have a lot of CLOSE WAIT connections not close

https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HTTPASYNC/issues/HTTPASYNC-109?filter=recentlyviewed
